# Append different number of spaces at the end of a string

Tags: sed, spaces

I want to add different number of spaces after a string:

I have used

```
echo "444rrrr" | sed 's/$/     /'
```

This adds 5 space after `"444rrrr"`. Since I do not know the number of spaces that I have to add before hand. Is there away to tell the "sed" command to vary the spaces that I want to append at the end of each string ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this, note the `_` just for example, since spaces are not easy to see here. you can change it into space.

```
kent$  n=5                                                       

kent$  echo "444rrr"|awk -vn="$n" '{for(i=1;i<=n;i++)$0=$0 "_"}1'
444rrr_____
```